# Beamer spacing inside equation

Tags: beamer, equations, formatting

I have the following code and because the floors and ceilings are large they touch.  I want to add space between each line of the equation.  How do I do so?

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{equation*}
            \kappa =
            \begin{cases}
            \left \lfloor{\frac{n}{k}}\right \rfloor &          j=1, 
            \left \lceil {\frac{n+1}{2}} \right \rceil  &            j=2\\
             n &            j \ge 3\\
            \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: I don't see, that `\floors` and `ceils` would touch. You should extend your code fragment to complete small document and add result of its compilation.

Answer (score 1):

**Is that what You needed?**

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\[
            \kappa =
            \begin{cases}
            
            \left \lfloor{\frac{n}{k}}\right \rfloor &          j=1, \\[1cm]
            \left \lceil {\frac{n+1}{2}} \right \rceil  &            j=2\\[1cm]
             n &            j \ge 3\\
            \end{cases}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```